# How to use values (as Column) in function (from functions object) where Scala non-SQL types are expected?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'd like to undertand how I can dynamically add number of days to a given timestamp: I tried something similar to the example shown below. The issue here is that the second argument is expected to be of type `Int`, however in my case it returns type `Column`. How do I unbox this / get the actual value?  (The code examples below might not be 100% correct as I write this from top of my head ... I don't have the actual code with me currently)

```
myDataset.withColumn("finalDate",date_add(col("date"),col("no_of_days")))
```

I tried casting:

```
myDataset.withColumn("finalDate",date_add(col("date"),col("no_of_days").cast(IntegerType)))
```

But this did not help either. So how is it possible to solve this?

I did find a workaround by using `selectExpr`:

```
myDataset.selectExpr("date_add(date,no_of_days) as finalDate")
```

While this works, I still would like to understand how to get the same result with `withColumn`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`withColumn("finalDate", expr("date_add(date,no_of_days)"))`

The above syntax should work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So other than going down the SQL expression route there is no other way then? `expr` is quite similar to `selectExpr` if I understood this correctly. While it is great to see it working this way, I really would like to understand if there is no other option. (I know I am being a bit picky here ...)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible as you'd have to use two separate similar-looking type systems - Scala's and Spark SQL's.

What you call *a workaround by using selectExpr* is probably the only way to do it as you're confined in a single type system, in Spark SQL's and since the parameters are all defined in Spark SQL's "realm" that's the only possible way.

```
myDataset.selectExpr("date_add(date,no_of_days) as finalDate")
```

BTW, you've just showed me another reason where support for SQL is different from Dataset's Query DSL. It's about the source of the parameters to functions -- only from structured data sources, only from Scala or a mixture thereof (as in UDFs and UDAFs). Thanks!